# How do I switch off the internet after use on the Samsung Spica?

Tags: internet, mobile-data

Using the Spica for the first time. How do I know if I am off the internet after using the phone to browse?

Comment: You should be able to switch off Mobile Data from Settings -> Wireless & Network or from the long-press Power menu.

Comment: Also, most Samsung devices have a "power menu" inside the notification area (which you can drag down). This should include a symbol with two arrows (up and down) which you simply can tap to enable/disable mobile data.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know if I am off the internet after using the phone to browse?

You can look at the signal bar, the signal bar would be grayscale when it's not connected to the internet, green if it's connected, and have arrows when actively transmitting data.

> How do I switch off the internet after use on the Samsung Spica?

The phone will only connect when it needs to, such as when you're browsing or when an app needs to check for update. Unless you're charged by connection time (I don't know any carrier that does that, most critters charge by amount of transmitted data), there's no need to disable them manually when you're not using it. If you need to disable Mobile Data though, you can do that in the Settings > Wireless & Network.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest auto disabling WiFi when your phone is locked. This will not only make sure no data is being transmitted, but also save a LOT of battery. Im sure there are *many* ways of going about this, but this is the easiest and most reliable method that I know of.

Also, here is how to tell your WiFi status:

---

- No WiFi icon = WiFi off
- WiFi icon grey = WiFi on, but not connected
- Wifi icon blue = WiFi on and connected
- Up and Down arrows on WiFi icon = WiFi transmitting or receiving data

---

If you just follow the instructions I've provided below, you should have satisfying results in just a few minutes!

---

1. Download **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** from the **Play Store.**
2. Open **Tasker** and click the `+` button. Now click **Event** → **Display** → **Display Off.**
3. Click the **gear** (back button) in the **top left corner.** A pop up menu will appear. Select **New Task** and name it `Display Off`.
4. Tap `+` → **Net** → **WiFi** and make sure the box that says **Set** is set to `Off`.
5. Click the gear (back) twice so that you end up on the **Profiles** screen.
6. Now click `+` again, then **Event** → **Display** → **Display On.**
7. Tap the gear (back) and then select **New Task**. Name it something along the lines of `Display On`.
8. Click `+` → **Net** → **WiFi** and change **Set** to `On`. Now exit back to the **Profiles** tab. You should now have both **Display Off** and **Display On.**
9. In the **Profiles** tab to the right of your conditions, there are **On/ Off** toggles. Turn both of these to <kbd>Off</kbd> and then back to <kbd>On</kbd>.
10. Simply exit out of **Tasker** and you're done!

---

Good luck and I hope this helps you!